# How to use extension with expression parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

How can I use this extension?

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> MyOrderByType<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Expression<Func<TSource, string>> predicate)
{
    return condition ? source.OrderBy(predicate) : source.OrderByDescending(predicate);
}
```

I used it this way:

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    result = ctx.Users
       .MyOrderByType(sortType,p=>sortKey)
        .ToList();                
}
```

search method:

```
 public List<User> Search(string name, string sortKey, bool sortType)
{
    List<User> result;
     using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
            {
                result = ctx.Users
.where(u => u.name.contains(name))
.MyOrderByType(sortType, p => sortKey)
}
}
.ToList();

            }
            return result;
}
```

in code behind:

```
 bool sortType=ddlSortType.SelectedValue=="0"?true:false;
string sortKey=ddlSortKey.SelectedValue;
var lstUser = userService.Search(txtName.Text,sortType,sortKey);
```

but it doesn't sort the result.

What is wrong?

Comment: Due to the lack of missing informations how `MyEntities` look like and what `sortKey` is, this is just a wild guess: I think it's nothing wrong with your extension method, but I guess `sortKey` is not a simple `key` but a complex key. So please provide more contextual information about your setup. And please provide a full compile example.

Comment: Note that `Queryable.OrderBy` returns an `IOrderedQueryable`, not an `IQueryable`. You might want to do the same if you want to implement `ThenBy` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't pass the predicate correctly. When calling your `MyOrderByType` extensions, you typically choose which field of `User` you want to sort by. Use your `sortKey` string to create a proper predicate. I handled cases to resolve an expression for name and email, you can easily add another fields to sort by.

```
var sortKey = "name"; // use your sortKey
Expression<Func<User, string>> sortExpression;
switch (sortKey)
{
    case "email":
        sortExpression = x => x.Email;
        break;
    case "name":
        sortExpression = x => x.Name;
        break;
    default:
        sortExpression = x => x.Name;
        break;
}

using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    result = ctx.Users
       .MyOrderByType(sortType, sortExpression)
       .ToList();                
}

// defined below
public class User
{
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public string Email {get;set;}

    // other properties
}

public class MyEntities : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. Right, it can be any property of User, so the extension method will sort it by whatever field of User you want.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you, please elaborate?

Comment: Look at my example again, the answer is there. Your extension method doesn't have to know what sortKey you'll pass to it, it could be any property of User. It's purpose is just to sort the collection of users by some of its fields, in ascending or descending order. To choose the property you write lambda expression `x => x.Name`, or `x => x.Email`. But when you call method `MyOrderByType`, it's supposed that you know by which property you want to sort: `ctx.Users.MyOrderByType(sortType, x => x.Email)`.

Comment: Look at my updates too, I resolve field expression by sortKey string, you need to use it. The type is sortKey is string, but you have to use a predicate of type `Expression<Func<User, string>>` instead of sortKey to pass into extension method

Comment: if i want to sort by different type string,int.how do it?